# Mac USD usdview 'python' is dying

Tags: usd

I have installed USD on my Mac after a long battle. Finally it reaches the point where it said `Success...add xx to your PATH and PYTHONPATH`. I did this.

But when I now run `usdview` (through terminal OR by going to the execution file in the finder and clicking it) I get this error:

```
(base) MacBook-Pro-2:USD-20.11 x$ usdview

------------------------ 'python' is dying ------------------------
python crashed. FATAL ERROR: Failed axiom: ' Py_IsInitialized() '
in operator() at line 148 of /Users/x/Documents/x/USD-20.11/pxr/base/tf/pyTracing.cpp

The stack can be found in MacBook-Pro-2:/var/folders/xz/lfv32q8944s8gvb7zwlppkkm0000gq/T//st_python.37044
done.
------------------------------------------------------------------
Abort trap: 6
```

Does anyone know what this cause of this might be? I have been battling a long time without any success :(

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use conda:
`$conda deactivate`
And build USD by using the python on your OS:
`$python USD/build_scripts/build_usd.py /opt/local/USD`

I had the same issue and I couldn't find a way to make it work with conda. It seems that the USD build refer to the python installed on the OS. So when you try to execute the USD build with a different python from which it has been built, it crash.